# Receber código vindo de input

Tags: javascript, html

Como faço para tratar o texto vindo de input como string mesmo que sejam tags html?

Ex: se eu digitar

```
<b>texto</b>
```

em um campo input sem tratamento ele aparece assim **texto**, mas eu quero ele escrito mesmo assim:

```
<b>texto</b>
```

Comment: Você tá fazendo com javascript puro ou com jquery?

Comment: jQuery na maior parte, mas o que tiver mais fácil pra vc ja irá me ajudar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em javascript puro você pode fazer assim:

```js
texto.onkeyup = function() {
  
  resultado.textContent = this.value
    
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="texto">


<div id="resultado">
  
  
</div>
```

Em jQuery:

```js
$('#texto').keyup(function() {
  $('#resultado').text($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="texto">

<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Comment: legal, simples e prático. No caso o segredo está em `textContent`?

Comment: Exatamente, ao invés de usar innerHTML, usa o textContent, que ele ignora a interpretação das tags, coloquei um exemplo com jquery também!

Comment: Perfeito, obrigadão!